# Why doesn't incremental history search work in zsh?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to get rid of Oh-my-zsh and currently my biggest challenge is getting incremental history search working. I've acked and grepped my way through the code and there's no clues in site. I get this error :
`No such widget 'histrory-beginning-search-backward'`

EDIT:
I've tried this with the absolute least possible code, it still doesn't work. here's the reduced test case:

```
# key bindings
bindkey -v
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    RPS1="${${KEYMAP/vicmd/NORMAL}/(main|viins)/INSERT}"
    RPS2=$RPS1
    zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select

bindkey -M vicmd '^R' histrory-beginning-search-backward
bindkey -M viins '^R' histrory-beginning-search-backward
```

Here's my config, taken from the zsh config wizzard, my current zshrc and oh-my-zsh:

```
autoload zkbd
 # The following lines were added by compinstall

zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored _correct _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'zstyle ':completion:*' verbose true
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/jonathan/.zshrc'
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ''
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' use-cache 1
zstyle ':completion::complete:*' cache-path $HOME/.cache/zsh
#load colorstuff
autoload -Uz compinit
autoload -U colors && colors
compinit
# End of lines added by compinstall
# Lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=1000
SAVEHIST=1000
setopt extendedglob
unsetopt beep nomatch notify
# End of lines configured by zsh-newuser-install
setopt completealiases
# Ignore boring stuff
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:users' ignored-patterns \
adm amanda apache at avahi avahi-autoipd beaglidx bin cacti canna \
clamav daemon dbus distcache dnsmasq dovecot fax ftp games gdm \
gkrellmd gopher hacluster haldaemon halt hsqldb ident junkbust kdm \
ldap lp mail mailman mailnull man messagebus mldonkey mysql nagios \
named netdump news nfsnobody nobody nscd ntp nut nx obsrun openvpn \
operator pcap polkitd postfix postgres privoxy pulse pvm quagga radvd \
rpc rpcuser rpm rtkit scard shutdown squid sshd statd svn sync tftp \
usbmux uucp vcsa wwwrun xfs '_*'
zstyle ':completion:*:functions' ignored-patterns '_*'
# Completion dots
expand-or-complete-with-dots() {
    echo -n "\e[31m......\e[0m"
    zle expand-or-complete
    zle redisplay
}
zle -N expand-or-complete-with-dots
bindkey "^I" expand-or-complete-with-dots
# Prompt stuff *truncated*


# key bindings
bindkey -v
function zle-line-init zle-keymap-select {
    RPS1="${${KEYMAP/vicmd/NORMAL}/(main|viins)/INSERT}"
    RPS2=$RPS1
    zle reset-prompt
}
zle -N zle-line-init
zle -N zle-keymap-select

bindkey -M vicmd '^R' histrory-beginning-search-backward
bindkey -M viins '^R' histrory-beginning-search-backward

function run-again {
    zle up-history
    zle accept-line
}
zle -N run-again
bindkey -M viins '^W' run-again
bindkey -M vicmd '^W' run-again
bindkey -M viins ' ' magic-space # [Space] - do history expansion
bindkey '^[[1;5C' forward-word # [Ctrl-RightArrow] - move forward one word
bindkey '^[[1;5D' backward-word # [Ctrl-LeftArrow] - move backward one word
if [[ "${terminfo[kcbt]}" != "" ]]; then
bindkey -M viins "${terminfo[kcbt]}" reverse-menu-complete # [Shift-Tab] - move through the completion menu backwards
fi

dirstackfile="$HOME/.cache/zsh/dirs"
if [[ -f dirstackfile ]] && [[ $#dirstack -eq 0 ]]; then
    dirstack=( ${(f)"$(< $dirstackfile)"} )
    [[ -d $dirstack[1] ]] && builtin cd $dirstack[1]
fi
chpwd() {
    print -l $PWD ${(u)dirstack} > $dirstackfile
}

dirstacksize=20
setopt autopushd pushdsilent pushdtohome
# remove duplicate entries
setopt pushdignoredups
#revert plus and minus operators.
setopt pushdminus

#PATH info truncated
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Whoops... I had a typo, now I feel dumb. I had it as histrory, when it should be history..